# How can one see the size of the compiled subroutine in VBA Excel 2016?

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

After finding a "procedure to large" error on a specific subroutine of a module, I am refactoring the code in the module. I was curious on how effective the refactoring is at reducing the compiled code size.

So I was wondering if there is a way to see the size of the compiled code of a subroutine in a Module of Excel 2016?

My attempts so far have been limited to searching online for methods to determine the size of a compiled module or subroutine in VBA.

It led me to the limits of VBA as listed in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa240819(v=vs.60)). It does not mention a way to see the size of the procedure compiled, nor does it mention whether that is (practically) possible.

(As was mentioned in the comments, the current maximum size of the compiled procedure is 64K as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/procedure-too-large).)

1. I think the compiled procedure size is not 1 on 1 related to the number of lines. (Because that does not take into account short or long lines. But I am currently unsure about how the vba-procure is compiled, and consequently how lines contribute to the compiled file size, otherwise a solution could possibly be to compute the compiled file size.)
2. Nor is the procedure 1 on 1 dependent on the size of the code as stored as a '.txt' file. (because it can contain comments which do not contribute to the compiled code size)

**Disclamer** - I am well aware of the shortcomings of the old code I am modifying. That it is poorly written, I think this quote of Bill Gates illustrates it quite well:

> Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring
>   aircraft building progress by weight.

I think refactoring, and breaking the code up in shorter subroutines is an appropriate first step. To monitor this process, in combination with the hard bottleneck presented by VBA as the `Procedure too long`- error led me to this question.

Comment: Dear @Vityata, thank you for your suggestion on an estimation method of the compiled subroutine file size. From the information and forum posts I have seen so far the number of lines indeed appears to provide a good indicator to estimate the compiled subroutine file size. I think the number of lines in my subroutine is off-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't do that. VBA is compiled in several stages, it's part p-code, part interpreted, and at the end of the day the size in kb of the compiled procedure isn't what you need to work on.

---

You need to read about **Abstraction**, urgently. A procedure that triggers this compiler error is over 10K lines of code. A healthy procedure at the appropriate abstraction level might be somewhere between 500 and a thousand times smaller than that (not kidding) - **the size of the compiled code is absolutely meaningless**.

If you're worrying about the size of the compiled code, you're not writing the code for a human.

Code isn't written for a compiler to crunch and a runtime environment to run. Code is written for a human maintainer to read, understand, follow, debug, modify, extend, etc. Without any level of abstraction, code is a boring, excruciatingly mind-numbing series of executable statements that are invariably redundant, inefficient, and annoyingly bug-prone.

There are 3rd-party tools you can use to analyze VBA code. MZ-Tools 3.0 was free, but the latest version isn't. It has a feature that can tell you how many lines of code are in each procedure of each module, how much of it is commented-out, whether you have unused variables, etc.

[Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) is free and open-source, under active development (disclaimer: I own the project's repository), and has a *code metrics* feature (distinct from *code inspections*) that can probably help you identify the most problematic areas (although, parsing a 10K-liner module might take a while):

[image: Rubberduck Code Metrics]

*Lines* is your "lines of code" metric; *Cyclomatic Complexity* is a rough indicator of the different possible execution paths in your code (how much sense that metric makes at a module-level aggregate is debatable); *Maximum Nesting* is also an indicator of how badly "arrow-shaped" code might be.

High values in these metrics are a sign that you may need to *extract methods*.

Comment: `Cyclomatic Complexity` would be a great metric to include on a Dating site. Great post.  Moving forward, I will have to take a close look at both `Cyclomatic Complexity` and  `Maximum Nesting` as I write and refactor code.  That being said, I'm still going to be a "Lines of Code Nazi" because there is "personal sense of accomplishment" when I reduce the overall lines of code.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, Thank you for your elaborate answer. From 
your answer and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science) I currently understand that the size of the compiled code is meaningless because the difference in level of abstraction renders the effects of for example refactoring the subroutine code as practically untraceable. Thank you for the pointers to tools that allow me to work on the XY-problem more effectively! I am a great fan of the work put into Rubberduck, and I will be more persistent in applying it.

Comment: @a.t. You'll probably want to keep an eye out on the progress of the rewriting of the *Extract Method* refactoring tool ;-)

Comment: I love the sentiment, but this doesn’t answer the question Mug.